# SOAP UI testing a WebService with SOAP/JMS bindings, and WebSphere MQ transport

Tags: jms, soapui, ibm-mq, mq

I have been asked to test a service developed using SOAP/JMS bindings and WebSphere MQ as transport. I have setup the the hermesJMS to admin the WebSphere MQ Queues, and I can see the queues.

When I click run on SOAPUI, I get the following error:

```
com.eviware.soapui.model.iface.Request$SubmitException: 
com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.submit.RequestTransportRegistry$MissingTransportException: Missing 
protocol in endpoint [jms:jndi:JMSREQUESTQ?jndiConnectionFactoryName=JMSQCF&jndiInitialContextFactory=com.sun.jndi.fscontext.RefFSContextFactory&jndiURL=file:/C:/SOAPJNDIBindings&replyToName=JMSREPLYQ&targetService=SOAPNodesSample_JMS_Service]
```

Can somebody please tell me what **protocol in edpoint** am I missing here?